# on the sum $ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}J_{0} (2\pi nx) $

Tags: analysis, special-functions

given the zeroeth order Bessel function.. is then possible to compute the sum

$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}J_{0} (2\pi nx) $ for every 'x' positive real number ?

Comment: It seems for $x=1$ the series diverges to infinity.  But probably for most $x$ is converges conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

To investigate convergence, perhaps use:
$$
J_0(2\pi n x) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{nx}}\sin\left(2\pi n x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + O(n^{-3/2})\qquad\text{as } n \to +\infty
$$
and investigate convergence of 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{nx}}\sin\left(2\pi n x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$